# how to get value of custom attribute of customer in sales_orde_ place_after

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, customer, event-observer

I have created custom EAV attribute for customer called branch which is select field customer need to select one branch which he/she belongs to and its working fine.
**Note: Customer can change the branch for each order he/she placed.**

I have to store it in another table when customer place order with other customer attribute, so I used `sales_order_place_after` observer method. I am using

```
$orderInfo       = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Where I can get all the information about order. I am getting all the information using this code.

```
$customerInfo = array(
            'customer_id'=> $orderInfo->getCustomerId(),
            'first_name' => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(),
            'last_name'  => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getLastname(),
            'phone'      => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'email'      => $orderInfo->getCustomerEmail(),
            'address'    => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getData('street'),
            'zip_code'   => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getData('postcode'),
            'city'       => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
            'region'     => $orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getRegion()
            );
```

But I am not able to get my custom attribute, I used many ways to get it as follows.

```
1. Mage::log(print_r($orderInfo->getCustomerBranch(), true));
2. Mage::log(print_r($orderInfo->getBranch(), true));
3. Mage::log(print_r($orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getData('branch'), true));
4. Mage::log(print_r($orderInfo->getBillingAddress()->getBranch(), true));
```

Here is the code I used to create custom attribute

**install.php code**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'branch', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Branch',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => NULL,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'source' => 'customerbranch/entity_branch',
));
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'branch');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'branch')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
    ->save();
}
$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote');
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `customer_branch` varchar(255) NULL
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Config.xml code**

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <customerbranch_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Npm_CustomerBranch</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
        </customerbranch_setup>
    </resources>

    <fieldsets>
        <customer_branch>
            <branch><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></branch>
        </customer_branch>
    </fieldsets>
    <fieldsets>
        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <customer_branch>
                <to_customer>branch</to_customer>
            </customer_branch>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
        <customer_account>
            <branch>
                <to_quote>customer_branch</to_quote>
            </branch>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
    <fieldsets>
        <checkout_onepage_billing>
           <branch>
              <to_customer>*</to_customer>
           </branch>
        </checkout_onepage_billing>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Nothing is working.:{
How can I get my attribute value in sales_order_place_after observer method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you 'created custom EAV attribute'?

Comment: @JonathanHussey, I will add my install.php code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column `customer_branch` on the `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_order` tables.
then add this in your `config.xml` under the `fieldsets` tag.

```
<customer_account>
    <branch>
        <to_quote>customer_branch</to_quote>
    </branch>
</customer_account>
<sales_convert_quote>
    <customer_branch>
        <to_order>*</to_order>
    </customer_branch>
</sales_convert_quote>
```

Clear the cache.
For the next orders you whould be able to get the branch like this `$orderInfo->getCustomerBranch()`.

As a side effect, you will see the branch value in the order view page in the admin panel, below the name and e-mail address.